# how to get id of last inserted row in RDS Aurora in GraphQL mutation

Tags: graphql, amazon-rds, aws-appsync, amazon-aurora

I've a table with (id, price). id is autoincremented. I want to return the id and full data of last inserted row.

Resolver:

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "statements": [
        "insert into notes (price) VALUES (100)",
        "select * from notes WHERE id = $id"
    ]
}
```

How can I find the id of last inserted row. Second query of course will not work here as id is not known.

Does SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); work well in serverless context? How to store that variable and run third query?

Comment: Couldn't you just run this - `SELECT * FROM permlog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` to get the last inserted row?

Comment: this might give id of row inserted by someone else

Comment: You would need to store the Username or the user Id in the notes table and filter the queries based on the username as well. Another option would be to put the 2 statements in a transaction block inside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same issue. So far, this seems to work for us:

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "statements": [
        "INSERT INTO customer_addresses (`id`, `customerid`, `firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES (NULL, :CUSTOMERID, :FIRSTNAME, :LASTNAME)",
        "SELECT * FROM customer_addresses WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()"
    ],
    "variableMap": {
        ":CUSTOMERID": $context.args.customerid,
        ":FIRSTNAME": "$context.args.input.firstname",
        ":LASTNAME": "$context.args.input.lastname"
    }
}
```

Comment: What about if there is another insert between your INSERT and SELECT?
As far as I know, your 2 commands are not a transaction.